# Ant Deployment - other types to include with Profiles

Tags: deployment, profile, ant

So when using Ant/Force.com Migration Tool I gather that if you include Profiles in your package.xml, then related things such as Field Level Security will only be included if the relevant objects/types are also in the package.xml

That is:

- To get the Field Level Security part of the Profile, the Objects/CustomObjects need to be in the Package.xml
- to get the Page Layout Assignments part of the Profile, the page layouts need to be in the package.xml

etc

So my question is: What is the full list of metadata types that I need to include in my package.xml if I want to get *everything* that relates to Profiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects, classes, Visualforce pages, custom permissions, and page layouts are the five profile-based settings you'll need to select in your package.xml file. Field level security and record type settings will be selected by selecting objects. You'll need to do a describe to find all standard objects available for your org, because you can't wildcard standard objects.

Comment: Just complementing Mr. Fox's answer: you can get everyone of those using a wildcard (*) like "<members>*</members>" inside your "types" tag. You can see which ones are eligible for use with widlcards at this address (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm).

Comment: Thanks @Renato, although I've found that types from managed packages (e.g. tabs) dont get included by the wildcard and have to be listed manually